# Copy all cells in a column that have information to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit rusty on VBA, but I have some code that is doing part of what I need. I have a sheet that is populated by an Adobe distributed form. With that data, I need to find all cells in a particular set of columns that have data, and then copy that to a new sheet.
What I have so far is running fine, except that it copies the data to offset cells in the *same* sheet. I need it to copy to a different sheet.

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("'2020-07-09 MASTER Workplace Ins'!Z2:Z10")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Copy
        
'        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
'        Range("A1").Select
        
        For Each cel In SrchRng
            If InStr(1, cel.Value) > 0 Then
                cel.Offset(5, 0).Value = "-"
        
        
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Thank you SJR! I tried this but now it gives me a Run-time error: COPY method of Range class failed. This is what I changed to code to. What did I do wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyC()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("'2020-07-09 MASTER Workplace Ins'!Z2:Z10")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = "-"
        
        
'        For Each cel In SrchRng
'            If InStr(1, cel.Value) > 0 Then
'                cel.CopySheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = "-"
        
        
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have two loops doing the same thing? Your code doesn't paste anything.

Comment: You can write `cel.Copy Sheets("Sheet3").range("A1")` to paste to a different sheet.

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: SJR, I updated my question with the new code, but I am getting a Run-time error: COPY method of Range class failed. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's with the `.Value = "-"`?

Comment: Use the syntax in my previous comment. You don't need the `.Value = "-"`. Not only do you not need it, but it's wrong!

Comment: I honestly don't know. I grabbed this code from somewhere else. Is that something I should get rid of?

Comment: Btw you can probably do this without a loop, but I'm not 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you SJR... getting really close now. It is copying the information to the new sheet, but as I watch it, it is pasting the information into cell A1, but keeps pasting new information over the top of the previously pasted information. How do I get it to paste into cells A1, A2 A3  etc.. ?

Comment: I am taking data from a sheet that has information that will sometimes populate say cells Z2:Z10, or it may have some empty cells. All dependent on how the Adobe form is filled out. The Adobe form is a safety inspection work sheet with a comments section for each question. So, There is not always data in the "comments" cells(which would be the columns). Each line would be the findings a different inspector found.

Comment: The next step is for you to look up finding the first blank/last used row in a column - there are many examples online.